# Wordpress: display planned and published post

Tags: wordpress, post

I need some help to display published and planned post on wordpress.
I managed to do it in my sidebarleft.php with this piece of code :

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query('post_status=any&showposts=3');
```

But I also need to display them in index.php and categories.php (in the post count).
Right now my post are displayed like this :
index.php

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php theme_pagination(); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="listeItem">
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
    <span class="date"><?php echo the_time('j F Y') ?></span><br />
    <span class="lieu"><?php $lieux = get_post_custom_values('lieux'); echo $lieux[0]; ?></span><br />
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Lire la suite ...</a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php theme_pagination(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and categories.php :

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( array('hide_empty'=>'0', 'title_li'=>'', 'show_count'=>'1') ); ?>
</ul>
```

Does anyone knows a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'desc',
    'post_status'    => 'any'
));

while ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : $recentPosts->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;

$cats = get_categories(array(
    'type'     => 'post',
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby'  => 'slug',
    'asc'      => 'asc'
));

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo $cat->name;
}
```

Remmemer to pass ur correct args

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks, I managed to display the post as I wanted, here it goes with pagination if it helps an other lost soul :
`code`

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $category = get_the_category();
      $category_id = $category->cat_ID;
      $recentPosts = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby'        => 'date',
      'order'          => 'desc',
      'post_status'    => array('future', 'publish'),
      'category_id'=>$category_id,
      'showposts'=>5,
      'paged'=>$paged
 ));

      ?>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php theme_pagination(); ?>
           <?php while ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : $recentPosts->the_post();//while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <div class="listeItem">
           <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
           <span class="date"><?php echo the_time('j F Y') ?></span><br />
           <span class="lieu"><?php $lieux = get_post_custom_values('lieux'); echo $lieux[0]; ?></span><br />
           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Lire la suite ...</a>
           </div>
           <?php endwhile; ?>
           <?php theme_pagination(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
           <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(CATEGORIES_ID) ?>"><< Retour</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

`/code`
But for categories.php I can display the correct number of post (planned and published)
`code`
     'post',
               'taxonomy' => 'category',
               'orderby'  => 'slug',
               'asc'      => 'asc'
          ));

```
      foreach ($cats as $cat) {
           echo '<li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$cat->ID.'"><a href="'.get_permalink($cat->ID).'" title="Voir tous les articles classés dans '.$cat->name.'">'.$cat->name.'</a> ('.$cat->count.')
</li>';
      }
      ?>
```

$cat->count display the number of published post. I could add a WP_Query in the foreach but I'd like to do it an other way, if it's possible.